# Initialize a List<int> from a List<object> enumeration

Tags: c#

**Is it possible to initialize a `List` of `int` (primitives/value-types) with an enumeration of a `List` of `objects` that contain the desired integer property?**

I have a list of `records`, `List<Record>`, that have `RecordId's`.

Is it possible to initialize a `List<int>` of these `RecordId's` in the following vein:

```
List<Record> records;

List<int> recordIds = new List<int> { records.GetEnumerator().Current.RecordId };
```

Comment: `List<int> recordIds = records.Select(r => r.RecordID).ToList();`

Comment: `records.Select(r => r.RecordId)`? Learn to love Linq (LLL).

Comment: @itsme86 That's linq huh?... ahh, been meaning to learn it :)

Comment: It will change your life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either of these should work.

```
List<int> recordIds = new List<int>(records.Select(e => e.RecordId));
```

or

```
List<int> recordIds = records.Select(e => e.RecordId).ToList();
```

Under the covers these are practically identical so I'd use whichever you find is most readable.

Comment: The list will only have few elements, I just didn't want to write a loop.

Comment: Are the null-conditional and null-coalescing operators still required for linq statements? For example, `records.Select(e => e?.RecordId ?? 0).ToList();`

Comment: Only if you could have a `null` value in a `RecordId` or if you may have a list of records with `null` in it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be:

```
List<int> recordIds = new List<int>(records.Count);
foreach(var record in records)
      recordIds.Add(record.RecordId);
```

or using query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<int> recordIds = 
         from record in records
         select record.RecordId;
```

Comment: For extra flavor, you could use `new List<int>(records.Count)`, which would make this version produce better allocation patterns than the more obvious alternative.

Answer (score 1):

First, write a function that will accept a `record` and produce the desired integer.

```
public int GetID(Record r)
{
    return r.RecordId; 
}
```

You can also write is as a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator).

```
r => r.RecordId;
```

Then pass the function to LINQ's [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
//using System.Linq;
var result = records.Select(GetID);
```

Note that `GetID` is passed, not `GetID()`. You want to pass a reference to the function, not the result of the function.

You can also pass the lambda, which is a much more common way to do it:

```
var result = records.Select( r => r.RecordId );
```

If you want to end up with a list, just add `ToList()` to the end.

```
var result = record.Select( r => r.RecordId ).ToList();
```

Comment: I thought only an explicitly defined delegate could be passed as a reference, not an arbitrary function name "literal"? Has this been a standard C# feature forever (ie, function pointer)?

Comment: @samosaris: Unfortunately, yes. I say unfortunately because method groups (that's the name of that) have been a ripe source of confusion and bugs and overload resolution failures (although they're working on improving things). They're not pointers, just a way to refer to "all functions named `X` in scope", with implicit delegate conversions. That's just as tricky for the compiler as you might imagine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was trying to pass a Property as an out/ref parameter recently. I didn't even think of trying this, it just may be the fix, thanks!